# RPI3: how can I use the UART to communicate with a non-console device?

Tags: serial-console

I need to communicate via the RPi3 serial port with a device that only understands hex commands. I have read and implemented the steps shown in: [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3)
and my device communicates, but with frequent bursts of high baud rate interference that shuts down my device. My /boot/config.txt includes:
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-wifi
core_freq=250
I am running Jessie with apt-get update and apt-get upgrade complete. Can you tell me what is interfering with my python script and how to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

The system can use the serial link as a console to allow remote logins and may print system messages during boot.

Check that you have disabled these features (perhaps by using rsaspi-config).